# Adding key value to TempData results in a blank page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building my first .NETCoreApp using 1.0.0-rc2-final.   I am trying to insert a copy of Model into TempData so that it is accessible after postback.

I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session to my project.

I altered my Startup.cs to look like...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace GamesCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets();
            }
            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {   
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddAuthentication(
                SharedOptions => SharedOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication();

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
                Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
                CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"]
            });

            app.UseSession(new SessionOptions { IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following in one of my Controllers:

```
public IActionResult Index(Models.ScoreModel scoreModel)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(scoreModel.Username))
            {
                scoreModel.GameID = new System.Guid("b90ae557-7e03-4efa-9da1-1a4e89c1f629");
                scoreModel.Username = User.Identity.Name;
                scoreModel.Score = 0;
                scoreModel.ScoringStep = 1;
                TempData.Add("scoreModel", scoreModel);
            }
            return View(scoreModel);
        }
```

When I have the line with TempData in there, the page loads completely blank -- no error, no Shared Layout, etc.     If I remove that line, the View loads fine within the Shared Layout.   If I look at the debugger, the scoreModel is getting successfully added to TempData so that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: I think you need to move app.UseSession to be before app.UseCookieAuthentication

Comment: Moving app.UseSession had no positive effect on the issue.

Comment: TemDataDictionary only allows storing primitive types. If you enable runtime diagnostics (`app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`) you'll see that it complains about being unable to serialize the underlying type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

I moved to storing it in Session instead of TempData, using this page as an example:

http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/

I serialized the Model using the extension class outlined on the above page.

One note, is that since this page was written, `services.AddCaching();` has changed to `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();`

See this link for another sample: https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/dev/samples/SessionSample/Startup.cs